# How to return tags without attributes in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For example I have this tag:

```
<div class="some class name">Some sentence</div>
```

How can I return it like this:

```
<div>Some sentence</div>
```

I want to return it like that for all tags that have attributes, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clear your HTML document from all attributes, you can use `del tag.attrs`. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
    <div class="some class name">Some sentence</div>
    <span id="some_id">Some sentence 2</span>
    <div>Some sentence 3</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for t in soup.find_all():
    del t.attrs

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<div>Some sentence</div>
<span>Some sentence 2</span>
<div>Some sentence 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need `del` attribute

**Ex:**

```
s = '<div class="some class name">Some sentence</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
del soup.div['class']
print(soup.div)  # <div>Some sentence</div>
```